# Display Data Using Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

Is a pivot the best way for me to display this data?  I want to show id, uuid on the left then show each event1 across the top with a 1 if exists or a 0 if it does not. So look like this

```
id  uuid    cycle   run walk
1   mn12    1   1   0
2   cr23    0   0   1
3   bb11    1   0   0
```

This is the syntax I attempted, but it gives me an error of

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'For'

What should I alter in order to have my data display as desired?

```
create table #robschneider
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,event1 varchar(100)
  ,uuid int
)
create table #bigponyhorses
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,uuid int
  ,empid varchar(10)
)
Insert Into #robschneider Values ('cycle', '1'), ('run', '2'), ('walk', '3')
Insert Into #bigponyhorses VALUES ('1','mn12'), ('2','mn12'), ('3', 'cr23'), ('1', 'bb11')

;WITH data AS 
(
  select *
  FROM
  (
      Select
      [rs].[ID],
      [bph].[uuid]
      [rs].[event1],
      CASE when [bph].[uuid] is not null then '1' else '0' end As [Exists]
      from #robschneider rs
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT * 
                   FROM #bigponyhorses  
                   WHERE [rs].[uuid] = [uuid]) [bph]
  ) src
  pivot 
  (
      [Exists]
      For [planname] IN ('cycle', 'run', 'walk')
  ) piv
)
SELECT 
[rs].[ID],
[rs].[event1],
'cycle', 'run', 'walk'
FROM data
```

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the [Intranet].[dbo].[ResourceDevelopementCompletedCategories] table please? You also have a missing comma after [bph].[uuid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't include `[Intranet].[dbo].[ResourceDevelopementCompletedCategories]` in my test query below but hopefully I have provided enough code for you to understand the syntax you require.

```
create table #robschneider
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,event1 varchar(100)
  ,uuid int
)

Insert Into #robschneider Values ('cycle', '1'), ('run', '2'), ('walk', '3')

SELECT  ID
        ,uuid
        ,COALESCE(cycle, 0) AS [Cycle]
        ,COALESCE(run, 0) AS [Run]
        ,COALESCE(Walk, 0) AS [Walk]
FROM
(
    Select
    [rs].[ID],
    [rs].[uuid],
    [rs].[event1],
    CASE when [rs].[uuid] is not null then '1' else '0' end As [Exists]
    from #robschneider rs
) src
pivot 
(
    MAX([Exists]) For [event1] IN ([cycle], [run], [walk])
) piv
```

**UPDATE**
I have added the `COALESCE` statements to add the 0 values when `event1` doesn't exist.